# Finding upper and lower limits

Tags: real-analysis

What is the upper and lower limit of the given sequence $x_{n}=2n-7\left \lfloor\frac{2n}{7} \right \rfloor, n\in \mathbb{N}$? Again, I'm rather new to real analysis and I'd appreciate it if you explained the steps to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2n-7\left\lfloor\dfrac{2n}{7}\right\rfloor$ is the remainder you get when you divide $2n$ by $7$. As $n$ increases by $1$, $x_n$ will increase by $2 \mod 7$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$x_{n+7}=2(n+7)-7\lfloor \frac{2n+14}{7}\rfloor$$

$$=2n+14-7(\lfloor \frac{2n}{7}\rfloor +2)=x_n$$

So
$$\{x_n, n\in\Bbb N\}=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_7\}$$